# I try to pass my function from my first and second object into new function which take arguments of first and second object

Tags: javascript, function, object

```js
var myHonda = {
  color: 'red',
  wheels: 4,
  engine: {
    cylinders: 4,
    size: 2.2
  },
  distance: 40,
  time: 1,
  speed: function(distance, time) {
    distance = this.distance;
    time = this.time;
    console.log(distance / time);
    // console.log(`Current speed is ${this.distance * this.time} `);
  }

};

var myHonda2 = {
  color: 'red',
  wheels: 4,
  engine: {
    cylinders: 4,
    size: 2.2
  },
  distance: 20,
  time: 2,
  speed: function(distance, time) {
    distance = this.distance;
    time = this.time;
    console.log(distance / time + "kmph");
  }

};

let displaySpeed = function(myObject) {
  console.log(`Speed of Car is ${myObject.speed}`);
}

displaySpeed(myHonda);
displaySpeed(myHonda2);
```

Comment: So you wrote an title and posted some code, I dont see any question or wanted result. Or explanation of anything. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and what is [mre]

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the values of your function parameters, you probably don't need to pass them in as function parameters.

```
speed: function() {
   const distance = this.distance
   const time = this.time
   return distance / time
}
```

Just something I noticed off hand, you also may have to call speed `myObject.speed()` - which would return the `distance / time`